# Get the count of distinct elements from a list of lists using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have a structure which is a list of list. Below is the example :

Student Table

```
public partial class Students
{
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string MiddleName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public int Marks { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<StudentAddresses> StudentAddresses{ get; set; }
}

public partial class StudentAddresses
{
    public string HouseArea {get; set;}
    public string HouseCity {get; set;}
    public string HouseZipCode {get; set;}
}

var student = context.Students
              .Include(i => i.StudentAddresses)
              .Where(c => c.Marks > 50);
```

I need to get distinct HouseZipCode and the student counts for the same.

The below code is not working:

```
var test = student.GroupBy(g => g.StudentAddresses.Select(gs => gs.HouseZipCode ))
    .Select(s => new StudentModel { ZipCode= s.Key, StudentNumbers = s.Count() })
    .OrderBy(o => o.HouseZipCode )
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Hint: SelectMany then Distinct then Count

Comment: @John Distinct and Count don't make sense together.

Comment: @Euphoric Why not?

Comment: @canton7 Function of Distinct is to return all unique items in input once on output. So not sure what you would be counting.

Comment: @Euphoric The number of distinct items... `new[] { "A", "A", "B" }.Distinct().Count()` will give you `2`.

Comment: @canton7 Ok. That is true. But is that what OP wants? It seems there is confusion of what the output should be. Is it "count of unique ZipCodes and count of all Students" or "Count of students per ZipCode"?

Comment: @Euphoric Agreed that it's probably not what the OP's asking for

Comment: @Euphoric I think I misread the question. My bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are almost there:

```
var test = student
    .SelectMany(s => s.StudentAddresses) // get all addresses from students
    .GroupBy(adr => adr.HouseZipCode) // group addresses by zip code
    .Select(grp => new StudentModel { ZipCode= grp.Key, StudentNumbers = grp.Count() }) // count how many addresses have same zip code
    .OrderBy(o => o.ZipCode)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. Are you sure it's not missing something? Because out of this I only get 1 zipcode where as in my sql query, I can see 3 different zipcodes.

Comment: @TheFallenOne I see nothing wrong with my query. Can you check what is in student list and what addresses are there?